# Subclassing Pandas, modifying self

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-inheritance, subclassing

Assume you have a *DataFrame* object with some multi row and column data in it. You can then easily assign this onto itself to modify the object. For example:

```
test = test.iloc[0:10,:]
```

will only retain the first 10 rows of the original dataset.

I am trying to replicate this behaviour when I subclass Pandas with multiple inheritance. For example:

```
class data(pd.DataFrame, time, series):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(data, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return data
```

where *time* and *series* are classes that provide additional methods. Here, only series is relevant:

```
class series(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(series, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def keep10rows(self):
        self = self.iloc[0:10,:]
        return self
```

Now, I create a new class instance:

```
test = data()
```

now we can fill *test* with some data. If I apply:

```
result = test.keep10rows()
```

Here, *result* will look correct. However, *test.data* has not changed. Why? How can I achieve a change of the data inside the object?